# Mapping forms of "werden" in reported speech to its probable forms in direct speech

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, verb-usage

This post is on the forms of *werden* as highlighted in these passages from chapter '[Weg nach Ramses](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/amerika-9768/14)' of *Amerika* (*Der Verschollene*) by Frankz Kafka.

> Vieles erinnerte Karl an seine Heimat und er wußte nicht, ob er gut daran tue, New York zu verlassen und in das Innere des Landes zu gehen. In New York war das Meer und zu jeder Zeit die Möglichkeit der Rückkehr in die Heimat. Und so blieb er stehen und sagte zu seinen beiden Begleitern, er habe doch wieder Lust, in New York zu bleiben. Und als Delamarche ihn einfach weitertreiben wollte, ließ er sich nicht treiben und sagte, daß er doch wohl noch das Recht habe, über sich zu entscheiden. Der Irländer mußte erst vermitteln und erklären, daß Butterford viel schöner als New York sei, und beide mußten ihn noch sehr bitten, ehe er wieder weiterging. Und selbst dann wäre er noch nicht gegangen, wenn er sich nicht  gesagt hätte, daß es für ihn vielleicht besser sei, an einen Ort zu kommen, wo die Möglichkeit der Rückkehr in die Heimat keine so leichte sei. (A) Gewiß **werde** er dort besser arbeiten und vorwärtskommen, da ihn keine unnützen Gedanken hindern **würden**.
> Einmal fragte Karl, wo denn die Spedition Jakob liege, und sofort sah er Delamarches und Robinsons ausgestreckte Zeigefinger vielleicht auf den gleichen, vielleicht auf meilenweit entfernte Punkte gerichtet. Als sie dann weitergingen, fragte Karl, wann sie frühestens mit genügendem Verdienst nach New York zurückkehren könnten. Delamarche sagte, das könne schon ganz gut in einem Monat sein, denn in Butterford sei Arbeitermangel und die Löhne seien hoch. (B) Natürlich **würden** sie ihr Geld in eine gemeinsame Kasse legen, damit zufällige Unterschiede im Verdienst unter ihnen als Kameraden ausgeglichen **würden**. (C) Die gemeinsame Kasse gefiel Karl nicht, obwohl er als Lehrling natürlich weniger verdienen **würde** als ausgelernte Arbeiter. Überdies erwähnte Robinson, daß sie natürlich, wenn in Butterford keine Arbeit wäre, weiter wandern müßten, entweder um als Landarbeiter irgendwo unterzukommen oder vielleicht nach Kalifornien in die Goldwäschereien zu gehen, was, nach Robinsons ausführlichen Erzählungen zu schließen, sein liebster Plan war.

**QUESTION**

I want to ask whether *würden* as used above is the reported form of what would have been *werden* in direct speech, but will break down the question as follows.

1. For (A) do we get this direct form of speech?

   > Gewiß **werde** ich dort besser arbeiten und vorwärtskommen, da mich keine unnützen Gedanken hindern **werden**.
2. For (A) can we also get this?

   > Gewiß **werde** ich dort besser arbeiten und vorwärtskommen, da mich keine unnützen Gedanken hindern **würden**.
3. For (B), do we get?

   > Natürlich **werden** wir unser Geld in eine gemeinsame Kasse legen, damit zufällige Unterschiede im Verdienst unter uns als Kameraden ausgeglichen **werden**.
4. For (B), can we also get this?

   > Natürlich **würden** wir unser Geld in eine gemeinsame Kasse legen, damit zufällige Unterschiede im Verdienst unter uns als Kameraden ausgeglichen **würden**.
5. (C) does not appear to be reported speech.  Suppose then we want to narrate it in the present tense.  Would that have to be as follows?

   > Die gemeinsame Kasse gefällt Karl nicht, obwohl er als Lehrling natürlich weniger verdienen **würde** als ausgelernte Arbeiter.

**BACKGROUND**

On 1, my thought is that *hindern werden* would have given *hindern werden* in KI, which being indistinguishable from the indicative was replaced with KII, viz. *hindern würden* (while *werde er*, distinct from *wird er*, remained as was).

On 2, I am wondering whether *würden* can be used (as it were) to soften a statement.  But at least in English, a sentence that starts out in the indicative would likely end in the indicative.

> To be sure I **will** work and advance better there, because no useless thoughts **will** hinder me.

Karl seems to want to assure himself of his better prospects "there" and a *would* at the end would deflate this assurance.  But this would be a matter of style; replacing either *will* with *would* would not be ungrammatical.

On 4, again wondering whether in German *würden* is used to soften assertions, to give something like:

> Naturally we **would** put our money in a common pool, whereby incidental differences in wages among us as friends **would** be leveled out.

(Please don't make too much of *softening.*  I don't know what this is called in English grammar when people say they *would* as here.  Certainly Karl would be entitled to form the same expectation about pooling money whether Delamarche said *will* or *would*.)

On 5, it seems we cannot have *wird* in presentation narration; for suppose it went:

> Die gemeinsame Kasse gefällt Karl nicht, obwohl er als Lehrling natürlich weniger verdienen **wird** als ausgelernte Arbeiter.

That, in the past tense, would give us:

> Die gemeinsame Kasse gefiel Karl nicht, obwohl er als Lehrling natürlich weniger verdienen **wurde** als ausgelernte Arbeiter.

**ADDENDUM**

In your answer please give express yes-no answers to the five yes-no questions. Each of 1 through 4 asks whether the proposed direct speech is permissible for (deducible from) the indirect speech in the original text (whether or not other permissible forms exist). Question 5 asks whether the proposed sentence is the only permissible present-tense narration responding to the original (past tense) narration.

Comment: Correction to your last sentence: "weniger **verdienen wurde**" => "weniger **verdiente**" [or "**verdient hat**", but that is usually used in the idiomatic meaning of "deserves"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing one has to keep in mind when dealing with *Konjunktiv I* is that it shares many forms the *Indikativ* so it's often not clear whether it's *Konjunktiv* or not.

The usual solution to this problem is to replace *Konjunktiv I* by *Konjunktiv II* in those cases where it would be indistinguishable from *Indikativ*.

> Gewiß **werde** er dort besser arbeiten und vorwärtskommen, da ihn keine unnützen Gedanken hindern würden.

Here **werde** is clearly *Konjunktiv I* because *Indikativ* would be **wird**.

If you change the sentence to first person:

> Gewiß **werde** ich dort besser arbeiten und vorwärtskommen, da ihn keine unnützen Gedanken hindern würden.

Here it is not clear whether it's *Konjunktiv I* or *Indikativ*. Since *Indikativ* is used much more often, most readers would read the sentence as *Indikativ*.

To avoid this, change the sentence to *Konjunktiv II*:

> Gewiß **würde** ich dort besser arbeiten und vorwärtskommen, da ihn keine unnützen Gedanken hindern würden.

In my view the use of **würden**/**würde** in places where you might excpect **werden**/**werde** can be explained by the necessity to mark it clearly as reported speech.

Since in direct speech *Konjunktiv* becomes *Indikativ*:

1. is correct if used in the form "Karl dachte: 'Gewiß werde ich... '"
2. is somewhat off in my view
3. is correct if used in the form "Delamarche sagte: 'Natürlich werden wir ...'".
4. is not the proper translation if used as above.

In the case of 5. C) I would agree that it's not reported speech but about a hypothetical situation in the future, so yes, **würde** is appropriate.

> Die gemeinsame Kasse gefiel Karl nicht, obwohl er als Lehrling natürlich weniger verdienen wurde als ausgelernte Arbeiter.

This doesn't work because *wurde* can only be used if *werden* is used as a full verb, not as an auxilliary verb. So **würde** has to be used.

Comment: Thank you.  Please see ADDENDUM to the question.

Comment: Your direct speech sentence should be "Gewiß werde ich dort besser arbeiten und vorwärtskommen, da mich keine unnützen Gedanken hindern werden."

Comment: Are you sure that "in direct speech Konjunktiv becomes Indikativ"?  Shouldn't we rather say: "Konjunktiv in indirect speech may be a form of reporting either an Indikativ or what was already Konjunktiv in direct speech"?

Comment: I would want to pose these two additional questions about the sentence in question 4 (i.e. *Natürlich **würden** wir unser Geld in eine gemeinsame Kasse legen, damit zufällige Unterschiede im Verdienst unter uns als Kameraden ausgeglichen **würden**.*): (x) Is it a well-formed sentence? (y) When we indirectly report it, would it become (B), i.e. the original Kafka sentence? If you answer yes to both (x) and (y), that would just mean that the answer to question 4 should also be yes?

Comment: (x) yes, it is well formed. (y) IMHO yes. This means it is not completely clear if Konjunktiv II is used because of indirect speech or because of uncertainty. But since there is no condition and the speakers seem to be determined about going to Butterford I would use the indicative when transforming to direct speech. That's different from the following sentence where a condition ("wenn in Butterford keine Arbeit wäre") is given.

Answer (score 2):

Please understand indirect speech is a form to express uncertainty about what has really happened or whether something is a fact or not. You are telling "I wasn't there" with each verb.

In German an author **can** tell simple indirect speech apart from more complicated types of uncertainty by choosing *Konjunktiv I* or *Konjunktiv II*, **but he doesn't have to**. Kafka plays with this meta-uncertainty here, it's the desired effect. Another tricky part in this text are particles as *gewiß* and *natürlich*, which mean "it's certain" but in reality, they express uncertainty. You don't have to use *Konjunktiv* if you used such particles and if you do, you can completely obfuscate the reader about what's certain and what not.

That in mind, I recommend not to use this text for the study of *Konjunktiv* and its uses.

1. First part: direct speech and uncertain, second: direct speech and a fact.
2. First part: direct speech and uncertain, second: direct speech and uncertain.
3. direct speech and a fact. It expressed Karl is occupied of that idea as a Kibbuzim was. (That option is neglected in the next sentence.)
4. indirect speech and a fact or direct speech and uncertain.
5. direct speech and uncertain.

Again, please don't make too much "logical" assumptions about the *Konjunktiv* in this text. Kafka's idea was to riddle you, and the *Konjunktiv* is an extremely helpful tool. A native speaker would just hear to her guts and check if there was a bounty on Robinson's and Delamarche's head already.

Comment: Thank you. Please see ADDENDUM to the question.